# How to make a dictionary from 3 lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

So here are the 3 lists:

```
list1 = ['set1', 'set2', 'set3']
list2 = [1, 2, 3]
list3 = [2, 3, 4]
```

how do I get from there to this?:

```
dict1 = {'set1':(1,2), 'set2':(2,3), 'set3':(3,4)}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) with a [dictionary comprehension](http://www.diveintopython3.net/comprehensions.html#dictionarycomprehension), one-liner:

```
>>> {key: (value1, value2) for key, value1, value2 in zip(list1, list2, list3)}
{'set1': (1, 2), 'set2': (2, 3), 'set3': (3, 4)}
```

In Python3, you can do it this way ([extended unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)):

```
>>> {key: value for key, *value in zip(list1, list2, list3)}
{'set3': [3, 4], 'set1': [1, 2], 'set2': [2, 3]}
```

<sup>Though, I would prefer @alfasin's solution personally. There is no need for comprehension actually.</sup>

Comment: Yes @alfasin's answer seems to be a little faster also

Answer (score 4):

You can implement it by wrapping [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) calls:

```
dict(zip(list1, zip(list2, list3)))  # {'set1': (1, 2), 'set2': (2, 3), 'set3': (3, 4)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presuming `list1`, `list2` and `list3` have the same length:

```
>>> { list1[i]:(list2[i],list3[i]) for i in range(len(list1)) }
{'set1': (1, 2), 'set2': (2, 3), 'set3': (3, 4)}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the lists are same length, you can use `enumerate`.

```
list1 = ['set1', 'set2', 'set3']
list2 = [1, 2, 3]
list3 = [2, 3, 4]

dict1 = { element: (list2[index], list3[index]) for index,element in enumerate(list1)}

print dict1
#{'set1': (1, 2), 'set2': (2, 3), 'set3': (3, 4)}
```